# Copy hash of hash (HoH) into a key/value pair and back in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I wonder if this is possible and how: I have a hash of hashes `%backup` and I want to save it in a value of another hash of hashes, like this:

```
$globsessions{$session}{'backup'} = %backup;
```

and later on (of course) I want it back like this:

```
%backup = $globsessions{$session}{'backup'};
```

This is not working and I just lost a little here (maybe to less coffee...). The `%globsessions` is global in my app and should be reused.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Edit:
Using references as Neil suggested does not work, since the child owning `%backup` is dead the next time I need the data thus the reference is not valid anymore. So I have more a child/parent problem than a 'copy a hashofhashes' problem. But the solution from Neil for that is properly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have close to the right syntax, but cannot assign a hash directly as a value in another hash. Hash values are scalars. So you need to turn your `%backup` into a reference.

---

If you want to copy the data into the new location:

```
$globsessions{$session}{'backup'} = { %backup };
```

This is a shallow copy of contents of `%backup` - it is less efficient, but prevents over-writing keys or values in the original variable. Caveat: It doesn't copy deep structures, so if a value in `%backup` is another hash or array reference, then it could be modified. Use Storable's `dclone` if you want to make a deep copy.

---

If you want to maintain a reference back to the original hash:

```
$globsessions{$session}{'backup'} = \%backup;
```

This stores a reference to `%backup` - it is more efficient, but if you set `$globsessions{$session}{'backup'}{'foo'} = 'bar'` then you also change the original `%backup`

---

**To copy data back to %backup**:

A shallow copy will probably suffice:

```
%backup = %{ $globsessions{$session}{'backup'} };
```

Or using a deep copy, which is slower but safer with data, and requires `Storable`:

```
%backup = %{ dclone( $globsessions{$session}{'backup'} ) };
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, but `{ %backup }` and `\%backup` creating both a reference to `%backup` - at least this is strict complaining (Reference found where even-sized list expected....).
My problem is still the HoH back into '%backup' as data not as reference - I should have said, that the `%globsessions` is global and `%backup`is used in childs - so the reference is lost the next time I need it. Thats way I'm looking for COPYing ;)

Comment: @Jimmy Koerting: You will need to *de-reference* if copying to a hash variable: `%backup = %{ $globsessions{$session}{'backup'} };`

Comment: Having said that (and I've added to the answer) I didn't realise you were copying about the entries so much. Probably you should create a utility method that accesses the global data.

Comment: The reverse syntax was what I missed. But what I really missed (it worked in theory by accessing `$globsessions{$session}{'backup'}{'foo'}`) was that my communication between child and parent did not work properly ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the [`Clone`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Clone) module to duplicate the hash of hashes.

You need to dereference the stored data to move it back to a hash, but it would be more efficient to work with the stored *reference*.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Clone 'clone';

$globsessions{$session}{backup} = clone(\%backup);
```

then retrieve it using

```
my $backup = $globsessions{$session}{backup}
```

or, less efficiently, you can replicate the top-level hash elements using

```
my %backup = %{ $globsessions{$session}{backup} }
```

or, if you need another complete separate copy that you can modify without affecting the backup in `%globsessions`

```
my %backup = %{ clone($globsessions{$session}{backup}) }
```

**Note** that these code fragments are untested as I have no access to a Perl compiler at the moment.